# Benefits in Android to importing a library internally vs externally

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

Post ADT 17, non-Android libraries need to be included either in the "libs" folders of the project or exported via the "Order and Export" tab in the build path. What's the difference (if any) between importing a library **externally**:

[image: External1]

[image: External2]

And **internally**:

[image: Internal2]

[image: Internal1]

Is there an advantage to importing a library in a way that it is included in the "Android Dependencies" group?

Comment: good question i also want to known? +1 for that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How do you add external jar dependencies into your Android project's build path (internally or externally) make no difference on the actual build process (more specifically at compile and dex step), all it does is to tell build process where to looking for the required jars at compile and dex step.

The `Android Dependencies` element shown in `Java Build Path - Libraries` window is just another abstract layer that ADT plugin used for managing/grouping jar dependencies. where your external jar files (in your case android-support-v4.jar) appears (inside or outside `Android Dependencies`) in that window makes no difference.

Since r17, dependencies management has been much improved, and it is recommended to use libs/ directory store all jar dependencies (refer to you internal way), which is considered as a automation approach (as ADT plugin becomes more smarter now), see [Revisions for ADT 17.0.0](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html):

> New build features
>
> - Added feature to automatically setup JAR dependencies. Any .jar files in the /libs folder are added to the build configuration (similar to how the Ant build system works). Also, .jar files needed by library projects are also automatically added to projects that depend on those library projects. (more info)

However, you can still use the old way (refer to you external way) if you prefer, which is considered as a manual approach (as ADT plugin was stupid before), see [Recent Changes‎ for r17 Release](http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects):

> Important: If you are still referencing jar libraries manually instead of putting them under libs/ be aware of the following:
>
> - If the project is a Library project, these jar libraries will not be automatically visible to application projects. You should really move these to libs/
> - If the project is an application, this can work but you must make sure to mark the jar files as exported.

#### Is there an advantage to importing a library in a way that it is included in the "Android Dependencies" group?

Automation vs. Manual from dependency management perspective, automation is always considered as more errorless than manual in the world of computer science.

Comment: Do I still get duplication checking from ADT if I import a library "manually"?

Comment: Basically yes, check out the last section in [this link](http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects) to see how exactly SDK resolve duplicate dependency.

Answer (score 2):

The number one, show stopping, 'I can't believe they didn't test this', disadvantage of putting external jars in the libs directory is that you can't set the javadocs location for them, as the option shows as 'None (non modifiable)'.

Hence I still use Export option in build properties

Comment: The source attachment issue actually seems to be known to the team prior to release according to [this response](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27490#c6) on the issue tracker. Let's hope it is fixed soon :)

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with library dependency management of Android. for details see http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects

Comment: So is there a downside to just exporting external libraries? Will ADT not detect duplicates otherwise? I ask because I use a repo for all my libraries and I'd like to avoid creating a copy every time I want to use a library in one of my projects.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Eclipse FAQ](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-jdt-faq.htm)

> An internal resource resides in some project in the workbench and is therefore managed by the workbench; like other resources, these resources can be version managed by the workbench. An external resource is not part of the workbench and can be used only by reference. For example, a JRE is often external and very large, and there is no need to associate it with a VCM system.

So, quite simply, if you want to be able to manage a JAR as part as the project, exposing it to SCM and such, then treat it as a internal resource otherwise, treat it as a external resource. It will not make any difference in the APK produced in the end, its simply a eclipse thing.

If you want to avoid creating a copy each time you want to use your library, treat it as a external resource. But, can I suggest you look into [maven](http://maven.apache.org/) and the [android maven plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/), maven has a bit of a learning curve (especially if you are used to "make" or "ant" style build scripts), but it is very much worth the effort.